# Circle and tangent theorems

Tags: circles

Can we determine the length of the tangents from an exterior point to the circle if only the raidius of the circle is known.

Comment: You would need to know the distance from the centre to the exterior point

Comment: Use pythogerous theorem then. Its a right angled triangle.

Answer (score 0):

As commented by [David Quinn](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/187299), if you have the following diagram for your circle and tangent:

[image: Circle with Tangent]

in addition to knowing the length of the radius $\overline{OX}$, you would also need to know the length of the segment $\overline{OD}$ (i.e., the distance from the center of the circle to the exterior point), in order to be able to compute the length of the segment $\overline{DX}$ via the Pythagorean theorem:

$$\overline{DX} = \sqrt{\overline{OD}^2 - \overline{OX}^2}.$$